# Password input for Google Spreadsheet access via R

Tags: r, passwords, google-sheets

I want to access a Google Spreadsheet via R.
As I'm using my Google Account for a lot of things and sometimes do share code I'm not comfortable with storing the password for my Google Account in a script file.

What the best way to handle this login issue. Is there some way to create a token that R can use to login to Google docs that only works for google docs? Otherwise how do I deal with the issue? If it matters I use KeePass as my general password manager.

Answer (score 2):

One common trick is to store it in an environment variable. Nothing gets written to disk, and you can query it in R via

```
 Sys.getenv("NAMEOFMYVAR")
```

where `NAMEOFMYVAR` is the handle you use.

The downside is that this does not work for scripting.  For that you need to eventually write something down somewhere...

*Edit:* There is also [an API](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/overview) as a quick Google search reveals...